# PHPStan Symfony: no value type specified in iterable type array

Tags: php, symfony, phpstan

I wanted to test my little symfony project today with PHPStan, and I got this error when I want to test User Entity (Entity/User.php), which I don't have clue what does it mean:

```
  89     Method App\Entity\User::setRoles() has parameter $roles with no value type specified in iterable type array.
          See: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-no-value-type-specified-in-iterable-type
```

UserEntity was made with maker bundle, and the code inside is automatically made

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180, unique: true)]
    private string $username;

    /**
     * @var array <String>
     */
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
    private array $roles = [];

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private string $password;

    /**
     * @var Collection <int, Cart>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'customer', targetEntity: Cart::class)]
    private Collection $carts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->carts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $roles
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Cart>
     */
    public function getCarts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->carts;
    }

    public function addCart(Cart $cart): self
    {
        if (!$this->carts->contains($cart)) {
            $this->carts[] = $cart;
            $cart->setCustomer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCart(Cart $cart): self
    {
        if ($this->carts->removeElement($cart)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($cart->getCustomer() === $this) {
                $cart->setCustomer(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have included both doctrine and symfony packages for phpstan!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Just added thie above `setRoles()`

```
    /**
     * @param array<string> $roles
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }
```

More information and solution can be founded here: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-no-value-type-specified-in-iterable-type